# Zooming feature without selecting it using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, zoom

When I need to zoom to a feature, I have to select it first using  `layer.select(feature.id())` then I can zoom using `mapCanvas.zoomToSelected(layer)`.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.select(1)
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(layer)
```

`QgsMapCanvas` has only [`zoomToSelected()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#aaae29e271850de400a5bbb6acecf918c) method related to a layer. My problem is that I should not change the currently selected features when I want to zoom to another feature.

Is there a way to zoom to a feature without selecting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `setExtent` to the bounding box of the feature:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = {f.id():f.geometry().boundingBox() for f in layer.getFeatures()}
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(feats[1])
canvas.refresh()
```